# SQL Server : How to display all extended event tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-table, extended-events

When I run my query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'
```

I find there are 2 more tables added `trace_xe_action_map` and `trace_xe_event_map`, I realize then that these two siblings come from extended events but I remember inserting them into my database. Yet I don't know to which `xtype` they are both belonging to. Because if I run the above query in SQL Server Management Studio; I won't be able to find them. What query should I make to display them in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 4):

- [Source1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929097.aspx)

> **trace_xe_action_map (Transact-SQL)**
>   Contains one row for each Extended Events action that is mapped to a SQL Trace column ID. This table is stored in the master database, in the sys schema.
>   Applies to: SQL Server 2012+.

- [Source 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929169.aspx)

> **trace_xe_event_map (Transact-SQL)**
>   Contains one row for each Extended Events event that is mapped to a SQL Trace event class. This table is stored in the master database, in the sys schema.
>   Applies to: SQL Server 2012+.

You can use the following query to identify the Extended Events events that are equivalent to the SQL Trace event classes:

```
SELECT te.name, xe.package_name, xe.xe_event_name
FROM sys.trace_events AS te
LEFT JOIN sys.trace_xe_event_map AS xe
   ON te.trace_event_id = xe.trace_event_id
WHERE xe.trace_event_id IS NOT NULL
```

Not all event classes have equivalent Extended Events events. You can use the following query to list the event classes that do not have an Extended Events equivalent:

```
SELECT te.trace_event_id, te.name
FROM sys.trace_events AS te
LEFT JOIN sys.trace_xe_event_map AS xe
   ON te.trace_event_id = xe.trace_event_id
WHERE xe.trace_event_id IS NULL
```

---

By executing this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_objects    -- also FROM sys.system_objects
WHERE name like 'trace_xe_%'
```

You will have a result like this:

```
name                | object_id  | type | type_desc  
--------------------+------------+------+------------
trace_xe_action_map | -463397375 | U    | USER_TABLE
trace_xe_event_map  | -319884821 | U    | USER_TABLE
```